# Chrome extension DevTools calling function in content script is not defined?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Im making a Chrome extension. I need to apply some CSS to the element in the page which is selected in the Elements tab of the Chrome DevTools.

So far Ive added a DevTools pane which loads the javascript below. Every time an element is selected in the DevTools it's classes are logged (in the context of the new DevTools pane). So far this is working.

```
function logSelectedElementClassList() {
  chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
    "$0.classList",
    function (elem, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(elem);
    }
  );
}
logSelectedElementClassList();

chrome.devtools.panels.elements.onSelectionChanged.addListener(function () {
  logSelectedElementClassList();
});
```

The documentation says this:

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/devtools/#selected-element

> Passing the selected element to a content script

> The content script doesn't have direct access to the current selected element. However, any code you execute using inspectedWindow.eval() has access to the DevTools console and Console Utilities APIs. For example, in evaluated code you can use $0 to access the selected element.

> To pass the selected element to a content script:
> Create a method in the content script that takes the selected element as an argument.
> Call the method from the DevTools page using inspectedWindow.eval() with the useContentScriptContext: true option.

Ive tried to follow this. Ive changed my eval function:

```
  chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval("setSelectedElement($0)", {
    useContentScriptContext: true,
  });
```

And added this function to my content script:

```
function setSelectedElement(el: any) {
  console.log({ el });
  el.style.display = "none";
}
```

The content script was already being loaded on every page via this in the manifest.json:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["src/content.tsx"]
    }
  ],
```

However it didn't work. I couldn't see any console logs and the `display: none` style wasn't being applied. I also didn't have any errors.

I tried adding the callback to the eval function:

```
  chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
    "setSelectedElement($0)",
    {
      useContentScriptContext: true,
    },
    function (elem, err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log(elem);
    }
  );
```

`err` is coming back with:

```
isException: true,
value: "ReferenceError: setSelectedElement is not defined\n    at <anonymous>:1:1"
```

My understanding of the documentation is that the `setSelectedElement` function should be in scope?

UPDATE: I can get it working by attaching the function to the window object but this feels like a hack:

In the content script:

```
let prevEl: HTMLElement;
window.setSelectedElement = (el?: HTMLElement) => {
  if (!el) return;
  if (prevEl) {
    prevEl.style.opacity = "1";
  }
  el.style.opacity = "0.5";
  prevEl = el;
};
```

Eval function:

```
  chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.eval(
    "window.setSelectedElement($0)",
    { useContentScriptContext: true }
  );
```

Comment: Can anyone explain the down vote? Hard not to repeat the same mistake otherwise.

Comment: The documentation assumes the final script loaded by the browser only contains the function. This would make the function global i.e. exposed on `window`, but you use a bundler, so manually exposing the function on `window` is the correct solution when you use a bundler that hides all code inside IIFE, which is what all bundlers do by default. You can configure your bundler to expose the function explicitly via shimming or something like that, I don't remember.